# s3fs and Python os.walk

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm trying to figure out a way to read images from an S3 bucket.  Right now, my setup is to mount the bucket using s3fs, and then use a python script with `os.walk` to go through each individual image and do some manipulation on them using numpy.

However, the output of

```
os.walk("mnt/")
```

is nothing!  The command does not see any files within the mounted drive, although if I manually find the image

```
plt.imread("mnt/path/to/file")
```

I receive the image.  I am at my wits end trying to figure this out.  Any ideas?

Comment: This works in my testing.  Note that os.walk returns a generator which you must consume, either via a for loop or the list builtin.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
for dirpath, dirnames, filename in s3.walk(<your bucket name>):
# care about the how many directories your bucket have
    for filename in filenames:
        file_path = f'{dirpath}{filepath}'
            with s3.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                # do your numpy stuff with the "f" object
```

The code above will loop through the entire bucket, and works only if you have the file in the root of the bucket, if you have directories before, add an if statement, example:

```
if dirpath.split('/') == <depth of the directory with the files>:
```

Answer (score 1):

A mounted bucket from S3 doesn't behave like a normal file/directory in your filesystem, so statements like `os.walk` won't work as you'd expect. Your best bet is to use a library to search and interface with your S3 bucket from within Python itself.

I recommend looking into boto, which has a bunch of tools for interfacing with AWS. Also check out the AWS Python SDK.

Boto: https://github.com/boto/boto
AWS SDK for Python: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I have implemented something similar to os.walk() using just boto3.

see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945980/7445782) in related question.

Answer (score -1):

A few bugs here.  I think `{dirpath}{filepath}` should be `{dirpath}/{filename}` on line 5 and `filename` should be `filenames` on line 2, but otherwise helpful!

Comment: Please fix these bugs in the answer! It's a great answer but it would save so much time if it worked out of the box!