# How to get subkeys to iterate over and eventually the files inside them in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have AWS S3 key path as `bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3` that has subpaths as 
`bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3/fo_1, bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3/fo_2, bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3/fo_3` and so on. I want to iterate over these keys `fo_1, fo_2, fo_3 etc.` within the path `bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3`.

I tried the following but this doesn't work.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket = 'bucket-name'

prefix = 'fo1/fo2/fo3'
for obj in s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
     # Here when I print obj, it's a string with value as 'MaxKeys'
```

Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE:

```
s3://bucket-name/
        fo1/
           fo2/
              fo3/
                 fo_1/
                     file1
                     ...
                 fo_2/
                     file2
                     ...
                 fo_3/
                     file1
                     ...
                 fo_4/
                     file1
                     ...
                 ...
```

This is my structure and I am looking to get fo_1, fo_2, fo_3 and files inside it. I want everything inside object `fo3` and nothing outside of that.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate over"? Can you be more specific? When you say that your code doesn't work, what were you expecting it to do that is different?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to understand about Amazon S3 is that `folders do not exist`. Rather, objects are stored with their full path as their `Key` (filename).

For example, I could copy a file to a bucket using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/fo1/fo2/fo3/foo.txt
```

This would work even though the folders do not exist.

To make things convenient for humans, there is a "pretend" set of folders that are provided via the concept of a **common prefix**. Thus, in the management console, the folders would *appear* to be there. However, if the object was then deleted with:

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-buket/fo1/fo2/fo3/foo.txt
```

The result is that the folders would immediately disappear because *they never actually existed!*

Also for convenience, some Amazon S3 commands allow you to specify a `Prefix` and `Delimiter`. This can be used to, for example, only list objects in the `fo3` folder. What it is really doing is merely listing the objects that have a `Key` that starts with `fo1/fo2/fo3/`. When the `Key` for the object is returned, it will always have the full path to the object, because the `Key` actually *is* the full path. (There is no concept of a filename separate to the complete `Key`.)

So, if you want a listing of all files in `fo1` and `fo2` and `fo3`, you can do a listing with a `Prefix` of `fo1` and receive back all objects that start with `fo1/`, but this will include objects in sub-folders since they all have a prefix of `fo1/`.

**Bottom line:** Rather than thinking of old-fashioned directories, think of Amazon S3 as a flat storage structure. If necessary, you can do filtering of results in your own code.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong terminology and thanks for correcting me here. I meant key paths alone. When I say, it doesn't work, I mean I don't get `obj` as `bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3` after my for loop. I want to iterate after `bucket-name/fo1/fo2/fo3` that consists of some other objects.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are seeking. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure. Here is my S3 str:

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details, rather than trying to put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should examine the value returned by the `list_objects_v2()` call to understand the data that is being returned.

- If a Prefix has been specified, it returns the contents of the *exact prefix* that has been provided. Any sub-directories are returned as `CommonPrefixes`.
- If no Prefix is provided, all objects in the bucket are returned. You can then filter it yourself in code, as shown below.

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
s3_bucket = 'my-bucket'
prefix = 'fo1/fo2/fo3/'

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket)
for object in response['Contents']:
    if object['Key'].startswith(prefix):
        print(object['Key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the following piece of code can be of use for you. I expanded a bit on John's answer as I was looking for something similar. I basically recreated the os.walk() behavior, which you might be more familiar with

```
    import os
    import boto3
    
    # function to replicate os.walk behavior
    def s3walk( locations,prefix):
        
        # recursively add location to roots starting from prefix
        def processLocation( root,prefixLocal,location):
            # add new root location if not available
            if not prefixLocal in root:
                root[prefixLocal]=(set(),set())
            # check how many folders are available after prefix
            remainder = location[len(prefixLocal)+1:]
            structure = remainder.split('/')
            #if we are not yet in the folder of the file we need to continue with a larger prefix
            if len(structure)>1:
                # add folder dir
                root[prefixLocal][0].add(structure[0])
                #make sure file is added allong the way
                processLocation(root, prefixLocal+'/'+structure[0],location )
            else:
                # add to file
                root[prefixLocal][1].add(structure[0])
            
        root={}
        for location in locations:
            processLocation(root,prefix,location)
    
        return root.items()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":    
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-3')
        s3_bucket = 'bucket-name'
        prefix = 'fo1/fo2/fo3'
        
        # get list of objects with prefix 
        response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket,Prefix=prefix)
        # retrieve key values
        locations = [ object['Key'] for object in response['Contents']]
       
    
    
        for root, (subdir, files) in s3walk(locations,prefix):
            print(root,subdir,files)
```